# How to save web page informations?

Tags: java, android, web, wiki, android-sharedpreferences

I want my app to check some web page only once a day, so I want the data to be saved anded reloaded upon starting the app again.
I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/), but I can not save the result with `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`:

```
String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
SharedPreferences data;
SharedPreferences.Editor dataEditor;
String sDate = date.getString("date", "");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM  d");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

if(sDate != date){                             // <-- this does not work
   new Date().execute();
}
```

and `Date extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>:`

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements date = document.select("div#mp-otd p b");
String sDate = date.getText();
dataEtitor.setString("date", sDate)
dataEtitor.commit;
```

The "Date extends AyncTask" class always start.

Answer (score 0):

`editor.commit()` is used in order to save changes to shared preferences.

Add below line of code after setString

```
dataEtitor.commit(); // commit changes
```

**SharedPreferences Example as follow**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**Storing Data**

```
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long

editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

**Retrieving Data**

```
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

**Clearing or Deleting Data**

```
editor.remove("name"); // will delete key name
editor.remove("email"); // will delete key email

editor.commit(); // commit changes

editor.clear();
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Comment: Thank you.But I have my problem is it always start the class, and I don't now why.

Answer (score 0):

You muss use `!(sDate.equals(date)` in place of `sDate != date`, because the Strings are new and so they can not be compare each other.